# Reading file with fstream then closing and reading again wont work on Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, fstream

I'm having a problem that if I write to a file and read from it, then everything is fine. But then if I close it and reopen it, all the data is gone.

It's running on Android and the `filePath2` is from [getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) so I don't need permission to write to disk. Here's a minimal reproducible example that will run on a new JNI project on Android Studio:

```
    ALOGV(TAG, "gonna open filePath2: %s", filePath2.c_str());
    f.open(filePath2, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    if (f.is_open()) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "is open");
    } else {
        ALOGV(TAG, "is closed");
    }
    //Write some data to vector
    std::vector<char> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    //Write the vector to file
    f.write(v.data(), v.size());
    f.flush();
    //Lets read so we see that things were written to the file
    ALOGV(TAG, "seeking g and p to beggining");
    f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    f.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
    auto v2 = std::vector<char>(v.size());
    //Read things back to file
    f.read(v2.data(), v2.size());
    if (f) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "did read everything");
    } else {
        ALOGV(TAG, "did read only : %d", f.gcount());
    }
    //prints contents of the file
    auto* b1 = v2.data();
    for (int i=0; i<v2.size(); i++) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "b1[%d] = %d", i, b1[i]);
    }
    //finally closes the file
    f.close();
    //Lets open again to see if modifications were recorded permanently
    ALOGV(TAG, "gonna open filePath2: %s", filePath2.c_str());
    f.open(filePath2, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    if (f.is_open()) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "is open");
    } else {
        ALOGV(TAG, "is closed");
    }
    ALOGV(TAG, "seeking g and p to beggining");
    f.clear();
    f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    f.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<char> v3(v.size());
    f.read(v3.data(), v3.size());
    if (f) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "did read everything");
    } else {
        ALOGV(TAG, "did read only : %d", f.gcount());
    }
    //lets print the contents again:
    auto* b3 = v3.data();
    for (int i=0; i<v3.size(); i++) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "b3[%d] = %d", i, b3[i]);
    }
    f.close();
```

Here's the output:

```
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): gonna open filePath2: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_name.flutter_app/files/something_1.txt
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): is open
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): seeking g and p to beggining
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): did read everything
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b1[0] = 1
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b1[1] = 2
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b1[2] = 3
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b1[3] = 4
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b1[4] = 5
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): gonna open filePath2: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_name.flutter_app/files/something_1.txt
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): is open
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): seeking g and p to beggining
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): did read only : 0
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b3[0] = 0
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b3[1] = 0
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b3[2] = 0
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b3[3] = 0
V/MultiChannelRec.h(32416): b3[4] = 0
```

As you can see, before closing the file, I can read what I wrote. But after I close and open it again, I read zeros.

By using a file manager on Android, when I go to the app's folder, I see the file is created but has 0 bytes.

Comment: Note: if `f` is a `std::istream` or you can make it one, you can jettison most of the file open modes. `f.open(filePath2, std::ios_base::binary);` and Bob's yer uncle. You almost never want to read and write the same file at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the [`std::ios_base::trunc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) flag when re-opening the file:

> discard the contents of the stream when opening

After you write to the file, close it, and reopen it, you are wiping out everything you had previously written.

Comment: "Is it plugged in"

Comment: It worked, but It looks like if I do not use `trunc`, new files can't be opened. I can only open files that already exist. Is it true?

Comment: What do you WANT to happen?  Do you want to (re-)create a new file each time? Do you want to APPEND to an existing file each time, creating it if it does not exist yet?